# How to watch the resource contention between parent process and child process

Tags: c, process

The following is my test code:

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
pid_t pid;

/* create first child process */
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork error");
    exit(1);
}

if (pid > 0) {            // parent process
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid > 0) {        // parent process
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            printf("aaaaaaaaaaa\n");
        }
    } else {               // second child process
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            printf("cccccccccc\n");
        }
    }
} else {                   // first child process
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("bbbbbbbbbb\n");
    }
}

exit(0);
```

}

the three process will content to printf to stdout,but every time i run the code, it turns out that the three processes run one by one, i can't see the output i expect.I know this is because the cpu is too fast,it's almost impossible to see the output i expect.so i write another program which is a dead loop, just like this:
    while (1) {
        i++;
    }
to make the cpu use rate high,but i still can't see the output i expect.
what can i do?

Comment: @akp ,the output is like this:100 lines of aaaaaaaaaa\n, then follows 100 bbbbbbbbbb\n, then follows 100 cccccccccc\n.The output i expect is that the three parts are mixed with each other.Maybe like this:60 lines of aaaaaaaaaa\n, 100 lines of bbbbbbbbbb\n, 50 lines of cccccccccc\n, 40 lines of aaaaaaaaaa\n, 50 lines of cccccccccc\n. But the cpu seems too fast, i can't see some output like this

Comment: ur code is working fine & it's generating random output on my system...i think it's only due to fst CPU...

Comment: I wonder how to make fast CPU generate random output.Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**it's totally depends on OS scheduling** as how much time it gives to a particular process.

so **if u fork a lot of processes then the time given to one process will be less then u can get desired result**....

but as in case of **low load CPU the time given to a process becomes more then its quite possible to have enough time to print thousands of output in it's time quantum allocated to the given process that's why u are getting the specified(by u) results**...

Comment: maybe i should try to understand how linux scheduled processes in detail.Linux kernel is so difficult